# Does Azure OCR support Arabic and Hindi languages?

Tags: azure, computer-vision, ocr

I want to know if OCR of Microsoft supports Arabic and Hindi languages?
I have read in the documentation that it supports the mentioned languages but when I send an image containing Arabic or Hindi texts, the result is very wrong as you can see in the image.
Is there any way to change the language of the text manually in their official demo (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision) or is there any other website where I can test Azure OCR service fully?  [image]

Comment: good question.  International support is necessary to give fair access to Azure services to people of all nations, languages and backgrounds.    It allows us to build truly fair and ethical global software services that consider a global audience.  This question deserves 100 upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Hindi is not one of the supported languages listed under the Optical Character Recognition (OCR) section, but is listed under Image analysis with a green tick for 'tags' only.

An alternative [Azure OCR API](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/technology/azure-ocr/) which CAN read [Hindi](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/downloads/azure-ocr-hindi-sof.zip) (and many other Indian lanaguages such as Assamese, Devanagari, Gujarati, Gurmukhi, Kannada, Malayalam, Marathi, Nepali, Panjabi, Sanskrit, Sindhi, Sinhala, Tamil, Telugu) is IronOCR which includes one-click support for [125 supported languages](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/languages/).

```
//PM> Install-Package IronOcr.Languages.Hindi
using IronOcr;

var Ocr = new IronTesseract();
Ocr.Language = OcrLanguage.Hindi;
using (var Input = new OcrInput(@"images\Hindi.png"))
    {
    var Result = Ocr.Read(Input);
    Var AllText =  Result.Text
    }
```

Here's a full tutorial by Wade Gausden on [Azure OCR In .NET](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2021/08/25/azure-ocr-in-net-on-easy-mode-with-ironocr/) with IronOCR which covers running Ocr in Azure.

Comment: Excellent.  Cheap and full Azure OCR support for Arabic and Hindi. 
This tutorial is amazing.

Comment: Azure OCR Instructions in Hindi https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/languages/hindi-hi/

Comment: Azure OCR Instructions in Arabic https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/languages/arabic-ar/

Answer (score 0):

Hindi is not supported

Arabic is supported via the OCR API

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/language-support

Comment: Dear I know it is supported according to the documentation as I mentioned the question. My question was that where I can test it for the arabic text.